# What did Santana say to Riddick?

Tags: riddick-franchise, riddick-2013

When Riddick was about to be slain Santana says something to him in Spanish. What did he say?

FYI I purchased the movie from the PlayStation store and it does not have subtitles.

Comment: What time code?

Comment: I'll have to check when I get home but it's about five seconds before the rain hits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He says...

> "*Final di partid, amigo*".

...which literally translates (in bad Spanish) into

> "[this is the] *end of the game/journey* [for you], *my friend*"

---

Please note that given that he's planning to kill Riddick, I'd argue that Santana's use of the term "Amigo" (*friend*) is intended ironically and that he's not actually Riddick's friend at all.